# Linux timer_setup function

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When I try to call the timer_setup() function I get the following error

```
 error: passing argument 2 of ‘init_timer_key’ from incompatible pointer type   [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  init_timer_key((_timer), (_fn), (_flags), NULL, NULL)
```

The code:

```
/* ... */
#include <linux/timer.h>

static struct timer_list my_timer;

void my_timer_callback(unsigned long data)
{
    pr_info("%s called (%ld).\n", __FUNCTION__, jiffies);
}

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    timer_setup(&my_timer, my_timer_callback, 0);
    return 0;
}

static void my_exit(void)
{
    return;
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
/* ... */
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: please provide an extract of your code which is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you want to use `setup_timer()`, not `timer_setup()` which has a prototype of

```
static inline void timer_setup(struct timer_list *timer,
                               void (*callback)(struct timer_list *),
                               unsigned int flags)
```

or change your timer function to

```
void my_timer_callback(struct timer_list  *timer)
{
...
}
```

Comment: My Linux version of timer.h file, that setup_timer is deprecated.

Comment: That fixed the issue.